# Why does gsub fail for this pair of string and hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, string, substitution

I am trying to replace parts of the string by picking certain words and then replacing them with values corresponding to them, stored in a hash. The example I'm working with is

```
s = '{{content}}, {{expected}}, {{description}}'
h = {"contents"=>"new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4}", "expected"=>"new java.util.ArrayList<Integer>(){{add(4);add(3);add(2);add(1);}}", "description"=>"example"}
result = s.gsub(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/) {|x| h[x]}
```

Basically trying to replace all keys inside double curly braces with their values but this does not seem to work and result remains ', , '. Not sure if the issue is with the way the hash is created or if the regex is written incorrectly.

Any help figuring this out is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
s = '{{contents}}, {{expected}}, {{description}}'
result = s.gsub(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/)

irb(main):013:0> result.as_json
=> ["{{contents}}", "{{expected}}", "{{description}}"]
```

Your key was like `"{{contents}}"` so when you access the `h[x]` the x would have the value with the curly braces. You need to run the following.

```
irb(main):014:0> result = s.gsub(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/) {|x| h[x.delete('{}')]}
=> "new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4}, new java.util.ArrayList<Integer>(){{add(4);add(3);add(2);add(1);}}, example"
```

Also the first key should be `contents` rather than `content`